# Add other jQuery function to each button in the same class

Tags: jquery

I want to add function that will remove two divs, to all buttons of removeButton class at my page. Example: first button function will remove div with id "Region0Div", second button function will remove div with id "Region1Div" etc..
Remove buttons are dynamically generated by AjaxFileUpload control, and i cant find it by id. I tried something like iterating, but it dont work becouse function is assigned to all buttons of class at the same time.

```
$(document).change(function () {
            $(".removeButton").click(function () {
                $("#Region" + itr + "Div").remove();
                $("#Comment" + itr + "Div").remove();
                itr = itr + 1;
            });
        });
```

EDIT:

I tried each but it still doesnt work, assigning Region0Div remove to all buttons.

```
var itr = 0;

        $(document).change(function () {

            $(".removeButton").each(function () {
                console.log(itr);
                $(this).click(function () {

                    $("#Region" + itr + "Div").remove();
                    $("#Comment" + itr + "Div").remove();
                    itr = itr + 1;
                });
            });
        });
```

If i put the itr = itr + 1 outside click function, in the each function, it also doesnt work.

Comment: Why are you doing `$(document).change()`?

Comment: Becouse when i select some file to ajax upload control the document changes and remove buttons appear. If i use document.ready i will not find any buttons at page start

Comment: @user2838197 but the document does not have the `change` event!

Comment: There must be ajaxUpload Control callback function.--- Have you tried using $.each()? Like e.g. $(".removeButton").each(function() { $(this).click(function(){ $(this).children("div").remove(); }); });

Comment: @AliExalter that would work.

Comment: But it works with change, it just add the same remove of Region0Div to all buttons - thats a problem

Comment: @Ali Exalter  Look at my edited question please

Comment: @user2838197 please write html structure here cant understand which divs are parent and child. The structure generated by AjaxUploader. Also tell me after document changes, does '.removeButton' generates again or it stays on document. OR try $(this).on('click',function(){});

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't assign event handlers when something happen.
The general rule is - assign event handlers to the elements that exist on the page and delegate:

let's assume you have a button like this:

```
<button class="removeButton" data-div1="d1" data-div2="d2">Remove</button>
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

and JS like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.removeButton', function () {
    var btn = $(this), id1 = btn.data('div1'), id2 = btn.data('div2');
    $('#' + id1).remove();
    $('#' + id2).remove();
});
```

If you do it this way you:

- only assign 1 event listener instead of as many as buttons;
- don't have to loop through then every time;
- don't have to update the handlers whenever you reload buttons;

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$(".removeButton").each()
```

you can loop through them and make changes one at a time.

[JQuery Each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("[id^=Region]" ).remove();
```

Or you can use `each()` to make the exact `id`

```
$("[id^=Region]").each(function(index, value){
    $("#Region" + index + "Div").remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this below code will do..

```
$(".removeButton").each(function (i) {
                $("#Region" + i + "Div").remove();
                $("#Comment" + i + "Div").remove();

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".removeButton").on("click", function(i){
    $("#Region" + i + "Div").remove();
    $("#Comment" + i + "Div").remove();
 });
```

hope this help you